# Django model lookup on reverse ManyToMany Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am somewhat new to Django and I'm trying to solve what is probably a fairly simple task. I have two models (Destination and Tour). Tour has a `ManyToManyField` to destination in that a tour can be assigned to multiple destinations.

```
class Destination(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, db_index=True, related_name='guide_destination')
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="guide/destination/")
    image_caption = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    subject_location = models.CharField('subject location', max_length=64, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    slideshow = FilerFolderField(null=True, blank=True)
    map_embed = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    seo_title = models.CharField(blank=True, help_text=u'Max 255 characters', max_length=255)
    seo_keywords = models.CharField(blank=True, help_text=u'Comma separated list of keywords. Max 255 characters.', max_length=255)
    seo_description = models.CharField(blank=True, help_text=u'Max 255 characters', max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("guide-destination-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

and

```
class Tour(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, db_index=True, related_name='guide_tour')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="guide/tour/")
    image_caption = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    subject_location = models.CharField('subject location', max_length=64, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    slideshow = FilerFolderField(null=True, blank=True, related_name='guide_tour')

    destinations = models.ManyToManyField(Destination, blank=True)
    experiences = models.ManyToManyField(Experience, blank=True)

    seo_title = models.CharField(blank=True, help_text=u'Max 255 characters', max_length=255)
    seo_keywords = models.CharField( blank=True, help_text=u'Comma separated list of keywords. Max 255 characters.', max_length=255)
    seo_description = models.CharField(blank=True, help_text=u'Max 255 characters', max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my view, I am able to display the one destination that I want ad have added in some filters to make sure it is bound to the proper `SITE_ID` and that it is active.

```
class DestinationDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = "guide/destination_detail.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Destination.objects.filter(site_id=settings.SITE_ID, active=True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(DestinationDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return ctx
```

Where I am struggling is how to add in the context that I want to pull all tours that have a destination that matches the destination you are currently looking at so I can have a list of related tours displayed under the content of the page. Is this something I do in the context data?

```
ctx['tour'] = models.Tour.objects.filter(
        site=settings.SITE_ID, destinations=self.destination)
```

Would I do it in the template somehow? I thought it might be a `select_related` but whenever I attempted to place that in, I always had an error that the tour couldn't be selected.

Comment: Are you having issues getting the `Queryset` or are you just asking where to put it (yes, in the context data)? `select_related` doesn't work on `ManyToMany`, but you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: `ctx['tour'] = models.Tour.objects.filter(
        site=settings.SITE_ID, destinations=self.destination)` - does this code not work?

Comment: Good question. The issue might be the `Queryset` which right now only pulls the destination information any nothing else.

Comment: @masnun I get this error when I add it to the context: ```'DestinationDetail' object has no attribute 'destination'```

Comment: That is because `self.destination` is not available, I was under the impression that you have somehow set it. Try: `ctx['tour'] = models.Tour.objects.filter( site=settings.SITE_ID, destinations=self.get_object())`

Comment: @masnun that did it!

Comment: ok, I am adding it as answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django generic details view has `get_object` method which would retrieve the instance for that details view. Instead of `self.destination`, please use `self.get_object`.

```
ctx['tour'] = models.Tour.objects.filter( site=settings.SITE_ID, destinations=self.get_object())
```